# Split sentences by Case change where two words are "stuck" together

Tags: html, excel, powerbi

I am attempting to clean up the following data which has been extracted from HTML.

Some sentences haven't quite split correctly with the Capitalised word at the start of one sentence "stuck" to the preceding word.

The image below illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

So in essence if there is a sentence like: `The boy plays with the ballThe Girl plays with the Console in a row`. This would split to:

```
The boy plays with the ball
The Girl plays with the Console
```

M code so far with the actual data ( must be run in power BI as uses Html.Table function which is not available in excel).

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Web.Contents("https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/14184/7/1"))}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "General Population - Hazard via oral route") then [Column1] else null),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] <> null)),
    #"Kept Last Rows" = Table.LastN(#"Filtered Rows", 1),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Kept Last Rows",{"Custom"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {{"Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("</dd><dt>", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Custom"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Text", each Html.Table([Custom], {{"Custom",":root"}})),
    #"Expanded Text" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Text", {"Custom"}, {"Custom.1"})
in
    #"Expanded Text"
```

Comment: Check on here, similar question was asked the other day.

Comment: What is your logic for the split. It isn't lowercase followed by uppercase (easy to do) as you state in your example as the screenshots show something different. i.e. explosureHazard has not been split in your screenshot but according to your boy/girl example, it should be.

Comment: @David Ah yes sorry typed this manually. Hazard should be split. Updated image now

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry do you just mean Stack overflow in general or did you post a similar question? Cant seem to find it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/4961700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image still looks incorrect (informationOverall is not split) but if you want to split by character transition, you can do so from the ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Ahh okay, I thought this would split words up and didn't even try. Thank you!

Comment: OP will need the lowercase to uppercase option as per post.